# How to add URL variable in HTML paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie to HTML. I googled the question and tried some code but it didn't work so I'm asking here for help.

**What I am trying to achieve:** replacing the ?? in the HTML paragraph with a value from a URL (for example: http://mysite.html?name=Ryan)

```
<p> Hello ??<br> Thanks for answering my question</p>
```

**My Questions:**
1. This Javascript should extract **Ryan** from the URL - is it correct?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var urlVar = getParameterByName('name');
});
</script>
```

2. If the code in Question 1 is correct, how do I place the value in `urlVar` (which is **Ryan**) instead of the ?? inside the HTML paragraph?

Comment: Would make more sense to have a span element with an id in the paragraph and replace it....

Comment: Is `urlVar` the value you expect it to be or not?  It's not really clear to me specifically what's being asked here.

Comment: @yuriy636 I think the javascript code extracts **Ryan**, my question is how to place the value of **Ryan** inside the HTML paragraph so it will render on the browser: "Hello **Ryan**, Thanks for answering my quesiotn"

Comment: This is pretty much what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618470/javascript-replace-html-using-innerhtml Only thing is that you would need to find a way to select the paragraph despite it not having an id or class. (Or adapt your HTML like the suggested comment or the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the HTML is already rendered, after which the javascript is being used.

In which case you need to have a handle to replace it.

`<p> Hello <span id="username">??</span> Thanks for answering my question</p>`

Now within the Javascript code you can use something like:

```
var urlVar = getParameterByName('name');
 document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = urlVar;
```

EDIT: 
`<p> Hello <span id="username">??</span> Thanks for answering my question</p>`

uses Jquery document.ready to execute the code after the DOM as been rendered

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
      // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var urlVar = getParameterByName('name');
    document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = urlVar;
});
</script>
```

Comment: copy paste your code to my site and it didn't work - any ideas why?

Comment: Probably because his remake of your function takes one parameter and the original two?

Comment: Not sure i might have made a mistake. 

Though within the code you posted i did see });  at the end of your code. its something that shouldn't if the code you posted is everything  there is. 

Also your code is never executed if thats every thing you have.

Comment: @NineMagics No his code can actually use only the 'name' parameter from what i can see. if no url is specified it takes the current url.

Comment: @spoofie The script does extract the url variable value (i.e Ryan) but it doesn't place it instead of ?? in 'username'

Comment: I made an error, i wrote Elment instead of Element. 
within document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = urlVar;

Comment: @spoofie finally solved it - not with `innerHTML` that didn't work for me instead I used `textContent` like this `document.getElementById("username").textContent=urlVar;` and it works

Comment: Great to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a hashbang in the URL? You can try this out:

```
    function getParameterByName = function(name, useHash) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(useHash ? location.hash : location.search);
        return results === null ? undefined : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Passing true or false as the useHash parameter